# tkinter treeview not resizing width when column width changes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have a frame containing a treeview and a button. When the button is pressed, the rows of the treeview are deleted, columns are re-created and headers named. Columns are set to stretch, and the tree itself is set to expand.

My understanding is that this configuration should cause the columns to stretch to match the containing frame.

On the first launch, columns are resized and the frame matches the expected size of the treeview. Then I press the button to re-assign and re-size the columns (the same function is called as in the initialization).

The columns resize but the treeview keeps the same overall width. If I drag the right edge of the window, the treeview shrinks with the frame. When the frame "contacts" the rightmost column, it seems to regain its "stretchiness", and columns grow/shrink as I resize the window.

Moreover, sometimes (every couple of launches), the width setting of the columns does NOT take on the *first* click of the button; I have never seen this problem on any subsequent clicks.

I've searched through several similar posts but they point to expand being false, but I have it set true in `self.tree.pack()`, as well as the containing frame in `listbox.pack()`. I tried without expand and fill in both pack() statements as well; the behavior is identical.

Why is the treeview not resizing when I resize the columns it contains? What might cause the first click to fail to resize the columns?

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    import random
    # import natsort as ns
        

    class MultiColumnListbox(tk.Frame):
        """Creates a multi-column "listbox" with sorting columns from a treeview class"""

        def __init__(self, master=None,  *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master,*args, **kwargs)
            # add a button to change columns
            tk.Button(self, text="change columns", command=self._populate_dummy).pack(anchor=tk.NW, pady=5)
            self.tree = ttk.Treeview(master=self, show="headings")  # don't show tree column
            self.tree.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)                   # place tree in the parent frame

            # initialize to random values
            self._populate_dummy()
            
        def _populate_dummy(self):
            # generate column names
            colnames = ["item number"]
            numcols = random.randint(1,6)
            colnames += ['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(numcols)]
            self.set_headers(colnames)

            # generate row contents
            rows = []
            for i in range(20):
                vals = ['item{}'.format(i)]
                for _ in range(numcols):
                    vals += [random.randint(1,100)]
                rows.append(tuple(vals))
            self.set_rows(rows)

        # set the table headers
        def set_headers(self, columns):
            self.tree.configure(columns=columns)
            
            for i, col in enumerate(columns):
                column_width = tkFont.Font().measure(col.title())
                self.tree.heading(i, text=col)
                self.tree.column(i, width=column_width, stretch=True)   # add column, set width to match header

        # set the row values
        def set_rows(self, rows):
            # clear rows
            for child in self.tree.get_children():
                self.tree.delete(child)
            # apply new rows
            for i, item in enumerate(rows):
                tags = [(), ('oddrow',)]
                self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item, tags=tags[i%2])
            self.tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background='gray80')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Multicolumn Treeview/Listbox")
        listbox = MultiColumnListbox(root)
        listbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
        root.mainloop()
```

This image shows the states of the program under conditions described in red.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have wrapped `set_headers()` with calls to get widths of the treeview and its containing frame (self), so _populate_dummy() is now:

```py
def _populate_dummy(self):
        # generate column names
        colnames = ["item number"]
        numcols = random.randint(1,6)
        colnames += ['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(numcols)] + []

        print("BEFORE")
        print("frame width: {}".format(frame_width))
        tree_width = self.tree.winfo_width()
        print("table width: {}".format(tree_width))
        self.set_headers(colnames)
        print("AFTER")
        frame_width = self.winfo_width()
        print("frame width: {}".format(frame_width))
        tree_width = self.tree.winfo_width()
        print("table width: {}".format(tree_width))
```

Interestingly, when the program calls _populate_dummy() in the constructor, this returns

```
BEFORE
frame width: 1
table width: 1
AFTER
frame width: 1
table width: 1
```

despite the visual appearance being something quite larger.
but thereafter, a (non-1) value. When I get the "non-resized" version (step 2 in the image), I get this:

```
frame width: 99
table width: 91
frame width: 99
table width: 91
```

When I get a table where the columns appear sized correctly, but the frame is large, I get this:

```
frame width: 1003
table width: 1003
frame width: 1003
table width: 1003
```

I should note that the width reported does not seem to correlate tot he number of columns, or even be consistent; I got 1003 from 2 columns once and 1203 from 2 columns another time.

This seems significant, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the treeview behaves this way in the current situation but
you can work around the issue of blank space by adding an empty heading to to the end of colnames in the _populate_dummy method

```
def _populate_dummy(self):
    # generate column names
    colnames = ["item number"]
    numcols = random.randint(1,6)
    colnames += ['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(numcols)] + ['']
    self.set_headers(colnames)
```

Then setting the empty column header width wider than the current main window width in the final line of the set_headers method

```
def set_headers(self, columns):
    self.tree.configure(columns=columns)
    for i, col in enumerate(columns):
        column_width = tkFont.Font().measure(col.title())
        self.tree.heading(i, text=col)
        self.tree.column(i, width=column_width, stretch=True)   # add column, set width to match header
    self.tree.column(i, width=self.winfo_width())
```